# php script ran from crontab times out if other scripts are ran at the same time

Tags: apache2, cron, amazon-s3, zend-framework

I have a server in my room with a duo-core processor and basic internet (nothing fancy)

I'm running ubuntu 11.04 and I'm running a php script from the crontab.

```
0 3 * * * php back_up_to_s3.php
```

This script takes about 20-30 minutes to run.  It works fine when run from the crontab, however if I run it at the same time as other scripts that take about 5-10 minutes to run.

```
0 3 * * * php back_up_to_s3.php
0 3 * * * php do_this.php
0 3 * * * php do_that.php
```

It doesn't finish.  My guess is that it's timing out.  Here is the source of `back_up_to_s3.php`

```
include('Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php');
include("connect_to_database.php");

$my_aws_key = '******';
$my_aws_secret_key = '******';
Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::setKeys($my_aws_key, $my_aws_secret_key);
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3();


$fileName = exec("date +'%m_%d_%y'") . '.tar';

$filePath ="/home/me/temp_db_backups/$fileName";

exec("mysqldump -h localhost -u root -ppassword DATABASE_NAME > $filePath");

$s3->putObject('myBucket/' . $fileName, file_get_contents($filePath),
    array(Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER =>
            Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PRIVATE,            
            Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER =>
            'audio/mpeg'
));                   

unlink($filePath);
```

I know the script doesn't finish because the tarred backup does not appear in my s3 bucket.  However the tar file gets created and is still in my `/home/me/temp_db_backups` so I know the script terminates while `$s3-putObject` executes.

Comment: Possibly try increasing max_execution_time in php.ini (probably /etc/php.ini).

Comment: This won't help since cli max_execution time is hardcoded to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello LedZeppelin (doubt if I will every get to say that :)
Instead of guessing what could be happening, redirect the output to a log file and you will know for sure

```
0 3 * * * php back_up_to_s3.php >/tmp/backup_cronoutput 2>&1
0 3 * * * php do_this.php >/tmp/do_this_cronoutput 2>&1
0 3 * * * php do_that.php >/tmp/do_that_cronoutput 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks kevin, I followed your advice and traced the error messages to a common problem other people have faced.